# Titanium createHttpClient runs after other vars declarations

Tags: javascript, mobile, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

I have this code in Titanium, that calls a PHP file on server that print the Name of user that match with id:

```
var myString;
var request = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
var url = "http://localhost/myPhp.php?id=1";
request.open("GET", url, false);
request.onload = function(){
    var newString = this.responseText;
    Ti.API.info(newString);
    myString = newString;
}

request.send();
Ti.API.info("result " + myString);
```

Titanium console prints me this:

- result undefined
- nameOfUser

Titanium seems to call first the code after request and then the request. So I can't change the value of a var with the responseText. How can I do it? And why it happens?

Sorry if somebody posted it here before, but I could not think in the keywords to search it here in StackOverflow

Thanks in advance =)

Answer (score 0):

the request is asynchronous, when you call `request.send()` it does not block execution. when the request completes, the `onload` event handler is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this:

```
var myString;
var request = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
var url = "http://localhost/myPhp.php?id=1";
request.open("GET", url, false);
request.onload = function(){
    var newString = this.responseText;
    Ti.API.info(newString);
    myString = newString;
    Ti.API.info("result " + myString);
}

request.send();
```

Simply place the Ti.API.info("result" + myString) log into the onload function. The onload function is called dynamically once the request has been fetched.

Comment: thank you! It works only inside the onload function...got it!

Answer (score 0):

Titanium createHttpClient request has to modes asynchronous and synchronous.

your line exicutes frist which prints "undefinde"
Ti.API.info("result " + myString);

and then response come  and it prints the name of the nameOfUser.

if you want to make your code run inline then you have to make your createHttpClient call synchronous. for which you have to set the parameter of createHttpClient

make the third parameter to true.

request.open("GET", url, true);

now it will run fine